# Why does Write-Error terminate the script?

Tags: powershell

Everything I read on the web tells me that Write-Error writes to the error stream, but does *not* terminate the script, and yet when the following script is run it clearly *does* terminate the script.

```
Write-Error "This should not terminate the script..."
Write-Information "... and it hasn't"
```

The output is:

```
D:\MyBitsAndBobs\writeerrortest.ps1 : This should not terminate the script...
At D:\MyBitsAndBobs\writeerrortest.ps1:3 char:1
+ Write-Error "This should not terminate the script..."
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,writeerrortest.ps1
```

The message ".. and it doesn't" is clearly never executed.
Can anyone shed any light on this apparently unexpected behaviour?

Comment: If you change `Write-Information` to `Write-Host` you will see both messages

Comment: Show us your `$ErrorActionPreference`

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the way [Write-Information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-information?view=powershell-7) by default works.

As per the docs:

> The $InformationPreference preference variable value determines
>   whether the message you provide to Write-Information is displayed at
>   the expected point in a script's operation. Because the default value
>   of this variable is SilentlyContinue, by default, informational
>   messages are not shown. If you don't want to change the value of
>   $InformationPreference, you can override its value by adding the
>   InformationAction common parameter to your command.

So in your case, either change `Write-Information` to `Write-Host` or use:

```
Write-Error "This should not terminate the script..."
Write-Information "... and it hasn't" -InformationAction Continue
```

Output:

> ```
> Write-Error "This should not terminate the script..."
> Write-information "... and it hasn't" -InformationAction Continue : This should not terminate the script...
>     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException
>
> ... and it hasn't
> ```

Comment: My bad, I should have set $InformationPreference = "Continue"

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your `$ErrorActionPreference` variable. By default it is set to Continue and indeed does not terminate the script. In your case it's probably set to Stop. Change it to `$ErrorActionPreference = [System.Management.Automation.ActionPreference]::Continue` and run your script again. There are more settings than these two, explore them.

Comment: I posed the question badly, my fault. If I set $InformationPreference = "Continue" then Write-Error does not terminate the script, however, if I also set $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop", then Write-Error DOES terminate the script, so the question should be, why does Write-Error terminate the script when $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop" - after all a call to Write-Error is not, in and of itself, an error.

Comment: @Dave Well, it's not some kind of a paradox, it's just how it works by desing. Write-Error generates an error, ErrorActionPreference controls how to treat it and Stop makes it a terminating error.